# How can I get the full text at SDL? (Not console)

Tags: c++, sdl, iostream, sdl-ttf

I am creating a menu for a game at C++ and I have a problem when I read a text file (.cfg), and I want to show it to the screen (With SDL,not console).

The problem is that in SDL, I only get the last line. Why is that?

Here is my code:

```
fstream characters;
characters.open("characters.cfg", ios::in);
while (getline(characters, line))
cout << line << endl;
```

And I create a string to show it with SDL_ttf:

```
void renderUI() {
SDL_Surface* textSurface;
SDL_Texture* textTexture;
SDL_Rect textRect;

SDL_Color white = { 255,255,255 };

textRect.w = 250;
textRect.h = 20;
textRect.x = 150;
textRect.y = 200;

string names = line;

textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(gameFont, names.c_str(), white);
textTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, textSurface);

if (textSurface == NULL)
{
    cout << "TTF_RenderText_Solid() Failed: " << TTF_GetError() << endl;
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(1);
}


SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, textTexture, NULL, &textRect);
}
```

And here a photo to show that I get the full text in the console, but not in SDL:

EXAMPLE PHOTO:

[image: Full text - no SDL]

Comment: Should you not move the rectangle to prevent overwriting what was previously written?

Comment: Looks like `line` itself is constantly overwritten in the `getline` loop. By the time `renderUI` gets a chance to draw anything [Highlander's Law](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcLjcSloXs) has kicked in and Shang Tsung is the last string standing.

Comment: You might want to store the lines in a `std::vector` or similar. But watch out. `lines` has the horrid stench of a global variable and could be changed while the getline loop is loading it or `renderUI` is reading it. Don't make the same mistake with a `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution. Here is the code:

```
fstream characters;
string line;
string text;

characters.open("characters.cfg", ios::in);
while (getline(characters, line))
{
    text = text + line + "\n";
}
characters.close();
```

And here´s the code of SDL_ttf and the solution to the line break problem with SDL:

```
    SDL_Surface* textSurface;
    SDL_Texture* textTexture;
    SDL_Rect textRect;
    SDL_Color white = { 255,255,255 };
    
    textRect.w = 250;
    textRect.h = 400;
    textRect.x = 150;
    textRect.y = 185;
   
    textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped(gameFont, text.c_str(), white, 500); 
    textTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, textSurface);

    // If TTF_RenderText_Solid() Fail

    if (textSurface == NULL)
    {
        cout << "TTF_RenderText_Solid() Failed: " << TTF_GetError() << endl;
        TTF_Quit();
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }
```

Used this for the line break problem with SDL_TTF:

```
TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped for be able to use line break
```

Comment: Could you explain what worked and why? Maybe point out the relevant differences between the code in your answer and the code in your question.

Comment: Sure, the thing is, that with this code you can read all the lines in a text file with the line break:   "text = text + line + "\n";" . And with this function "TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped" SDL_TTF allows to be able to read the line break "\n" , it takes additional parameter: width in pixels after which the text will break into next line (the width is the numer 500 at the end of the code).